# How To Call Api using HttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I created an API and it works great testing in postman, But When I try to call it from an asp.net core mvc project using HttpClientFactory, It doesn't work neither on Get by Id nor Delete. It works great on GetAll and Post though. I ran a debugger and realized that When I try to post any id (integer), It returns 0 value! Here is my API controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyWebAPIProject.Model;
using MyWebAPIProject.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyWebAPIProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PlayerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IPlayerRepository _playerRepository;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

        public PlayerController(IPlayerRepository playerRepository, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {
            _playerRepository = playerRepository;
            _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;

        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Player>>> GetAllPlayers()
        {
            var players = await _playerRepository.GetAllPlayers();
            return Ok(players);
        }
        [HttpGet("{playerName}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Player>> GetPlayerByName(string playerName)
        {
            var player = await _applicationDbContext.Players.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Name == playerName);
            if (player == null)
            {
                return NotFound("Such a player doesn't exists!");
            }
            return Ok(player);
        }
        [HttpGet("{id:int}", Name = "GetPlayer")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Player>> GetPlayerById(int id)
        {
            var player = await _playerRepository.GetPlayerById(id);
            if (player == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(player);

        }
        [HttpPatch("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Player>> UpdatePlayer(Player player, int id)
        {

            if (player == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (player.Id != id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                await _playerRepository.UpdatePlayer(player);
            return Ok(player);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Player>> CreatePlayer(Player player)
        {
            if (player == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            if (await _playerRepository.SamePlayerExists(player.Name))
                return BadRequest("Player with the same name already exists!");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _playerRepository.AddPlayer(player);
            }
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetPlayer", new { id = player.Id }, player);
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public ActionResult DeletePlayer(int id)
        {
            var playerToDelete = _applicationDbContext.Players.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            if (playerToDelete == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _applicationDbContext.Players.Remove(playerToDelete);
            _applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
            return NoContent();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller on MVC project

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MyMVCProject.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyMVCProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllPlayers()
        {
            List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/api/player");
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(apiString);
            }
            return View(players);
        }
        public ViewResult GetPlayer() => View();
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPlayer(int id)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/" + id);
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(apiString);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            }
            return View(player);
        }
        public ViewResult AddPlayer() => View();
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddPlayer(Player player)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/");
            if(player != null)
            {
                request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player),
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created)
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created;
                var apiString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(apiString);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            }
            return View(player);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePlayer(int id)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, "http://localhost:42045/api/player/" + id);
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            if(response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("GetAllPlayers");
                
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the View.cshtml to Get by Id

```
@model Player
@{ 
    ViewData["title"] = "Get Player";
}

@if(ViewBag.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
    <h2 class="text-center text-success">@ViewBag.StatusCode</h2>
 }
else
{
    <h2 class="text-center text-danger">@ViewBag.StatusCode</h2>
}
<h2>Get Player By Id</h2>
<form class="mt-3" method="post">
    <label for="playerId">Id:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="playerId" />
    </div> <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Player</button>
</form>

@if(Model!= null && ViewBag.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered text-center mt-3">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Nationality</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Model.Id</td>
                            <td>@Model.Name</td>
                            <td>@Model.Position</td>
                            <td>@Model.Nationality</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }
```

Comment: POST indicates the request has a body and is optional.  So the messages that fail have a body?  Is the ID a http header in the request?

Comment: I implemented this by reading an article about call API using HttpClient. I'm trying to call GetPlayerById (int id) on api Controller from GetPlayer (int id) on MVC controller and show the desired one by hitting button on the form with post method in a cshtml view. As I said the debugger showed an int value of 0! here is the article https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-consume-api/

Comment: Is there a reason that you’re posting a form to get a player by id? Seems like that should just be a link to a `GET` action method where the id would be a route value. I also don’t see why you would want to be routing through the MVC backend to access the api. Seems like you should rethink your design such that the views access the api directly—that is if you even need a separate api project.

Comment: As far as why you’re getting the default value for your `id` parameter, it looks like it’s because your form input is `playerId`. Try changing your action method parameter to `playerId` to get that binding to work.

Comment: You are right. I just tried to follow the instruction in the article. I was wondering why I can't pass id value into the form. Is it something wrong with the instruction or my implementation?